# Vertx HTTP client support caching

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I'm wondering how to add a cache config to Vertx http web client.

With Apache http client, I could do easily set the `setCacheConfig`

```
PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.setMaxTotal(configuration.getMaxTotalConnections());
    connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(configuration.getDefaultMaxConnectionsPerRoute());
    HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(configuration.getHost(), configuration.getPort());
    connectionManager.setMaxPerRoute(new HttpRoute(httpHost), configuration.getMaxConnectionsPerRoute());

    CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom()
        .setMaxCacheEntries(configuration.getMaxCacheEntries())
        .setMaxObjectSize(configuration.getMaxCacheObjectSize())
        .build();
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
        .setConnectTimeout(configuration.getRequestConnectTimeout())
        .setSocketTimeout(configuration.getRequestSocketTimeout())
        .build();
    httpClient = CachingHttpClients.custom()
        .setCacheConfig(cacheConfig)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .build();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's not supported as of 3.5.1. You can file an issue on the [Vert.x Web](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/). Pull requests welcome!